# Running JUnit from Java program in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

I am using JUnit for the first time, and what I have been asked to do is run the Junit tests programmatically by 'calling' it from within a java program. (All of this is in Eclipse)
Please note that right clicking on the file containing Junit tests and choosing 'Run as Junit test' works perfectly fine. Below is the structure of my project in eclipse (can't paste image as I am a new user, so providing the link)-

http://postimg.org/image/gplfswqm1/

I have used maven to get all the jars required. I am pasting the pom.xml too, in case that turns out to be relevant-

```
            <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
              <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
              <groupId>com.so.generic.automation</groupId>
              <artifactId>GenericAutomation</artifactId>
              <version>1.0</version>

              <properties>
                    <maven.compiler.version>2.3.2</maven.compiler.version>
                    <selenium.version>2.39.0</selenium.version>
                    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
                </properties>

                <build>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                    <testResources>
                        <testResource>
                            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                        </testResource>
                        <testResource>
                            <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
                        </testResource>
                    </testResources>
                    <plugins>
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                            <configuration>
                                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                                <source>1.6</source>
                                <target>1.6</target>
                            </configuration>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
                        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
                        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>junit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                        <version>${junit.version}</version>
                        <scope>test</scope>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                        <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.core</groupId>
                        <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.resources</artifactId>
                        <version>3.7.100</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
                        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
                        <version>3.3.0-v_771</version>
                    </dependency>


                </dependencies>

            </project>
```

In src/main/java, I have my Java program in file Framework.java
In src/test/java, I have my Junit tests named ProjectSpecificTests.java

What I need to do is somehow run this ProjectSpecificTests.java from inside Framework.java. I tried launching command prompt from Java code and calling java -cp ..... , but I am not able to understand very clearly what parameters should I pass there, as I keep getting errors of NoClassDefFoundException, ClassNotFoundException, etc. If I explicitly mention the location of the jars, like here-

```
            javac -cp "C:\\Users\\himanshuc\\.jenkins\\war\\WEB-INF\\lib\\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar";"C:\\Users\\himanshuc\\.m2\\repository\\org\\seleniumhq\\selenium\\selenium-firefox-driver\\2.42.0";"C:\\Users\\himanshuc\\.m2\\repository\\org\\seleniumhq\\selenium\\selenium-api\\2.42.0";"C:\\Users\\himanshuc\\.m2\\repository\\org\\seleniumhq\\selenium\\selenium-parent\\2.42.0";"C:\\Users\\himanshuc\\.m2\\repository\\org\\seleniumhq\\selenium\\selenium-remote-driver\\2.42.0";"C:\\Users\\himanshuc\\.m2\\repository\\org\\seleniumhq\\selenium\\selenium-support\\2.42.0";"C:\\Users\\himanshuc\\.m2\\repository\\junit\\junit\\4.11\\junit-4.11.jar" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore ProjectSpecificTests.java
```

I ran this from inside the folder-

```
            G:\FrameWorkSpace_HC\GenericAutomation\src\test\java\com\so\junit\tests
```

Then new error messages are thrown, like-

```
            ProjectSpecificTests.java:8: error: package com.so.generic.framework does not ex
            ist
            import com.so.generic.framework.Framework;
                                           ^
            ProjectSpecificTests.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
                    static Framework objFramework;
                           ^
              symbol:   class Framework
              location: class ProjectSpecificTests
            error: Class names, 'org.junit.runner.JUnitCore', are only accepted if annotatio
            n processing is explicitly requested
            ProjectSpecificTests.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
                            objFramework = new Framework();
                                               ^
              symbol:   class Framework
              location: class ProjectSpecificTests
            4 errors
```

Can anyone please guide me what am I missing here? I am fine with ANY solution which achieves the end result, not necessarily a command prompt one.

I am sorry if the question description is too long. This is my first attempt at asking a question on this forum. Apologies if I have made any mistakes.

Comment: put the junit.jar library in your classpath

Comment: this is a little weird? Framework.java is inside your application sources (src/main/java) while you try to run ProjectSpecificTests which is inside the test sources. The structure of the project itself looks fine. Why do you need to run the test from production code? Or is it just some part of the test you need? Or do you want to execute the tests within the software?

Comment: Actually the requirement is pretty much set for me. Can't do much there. The code inside src/main/java/Framework.java will remain pretty much the same in future, and the Junit tests will be inside the src/test/java/ProjectSpecificTests.java which would keep on changing from time to time. So you could think of Framework.java as the file which contains the generic methods which these tests would be using. And all of this basically works fine and is quite stable. But the new requirement states that this is to be all launched from command line instead of right click->Run as Junit Test

Comment: @AurA - tried that, mentioned that in one of the steps of my question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whew! Got it to work now. Here is the solution for any one facing a similar problem in future and needs a detailed solution -

**For normal JAVA files**

- Compiling it. I needed to go inside the folder which contained my java file (Framework.java). Now here, inside this file, I had calls to methods defined in other files. So, compiling only this file threw an error. So, I had to do this-

  ```
  javac -cp <list of all jars separated by ;> *.java
  ```

e.g.,

```
    javac -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar";"C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar";"C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\ext\zipfs.jar"; *.java
```

- Running this. My Framework.java file was under folder C:\abc\xyz\src\main\java\com\so\generic\framework\Framework.java, so to make sure java could track the package com.so.generic.framework, I moved up a few folder till 'java' and opened command prompt from there. Then I typed-

  ```
  java -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar";"C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\ext\zipfs.jar";"G:\abc\xyz\src\main\java" com.so.generic.framework.Framework
  ```

Please note the addition of the last parameter "G:\abc\xyz\src\main\java"  in the class path to make this work.

**For JUnit Tests**
Compilation process remains exactly the same. However to run, we need to change the last bit. Instead of simply writing com.so.generic.framework.Framework (in this case com.so.junit.tests.ProjectSpecificTests), we write this-

```
    java -cp "C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar";"C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\ext\zipfs.jar";"G:\abc\xyz\src\main\java";"G:\FrameWorkSpace_HC\GenericAutomation\src\test\java" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore com.so.junit.tests.ProjectSpecificTests
```

Hope this turns out to be useful to others.

Ciao